# The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, web-hosting, plesk

I hosted my MVC website in plesk by using FTP publish option of VS2013 and everything went fine, I mean all the required files were copied properly in the destination under **httpdocs** virtual directory. But I am getting below error now when I visit the URL:

[image: Server Error]

I have tried all the possible solutions mentioned in many links but no proper solution I have got so for! Its making me real confusing about this!

I have tried to apply solutions in **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10783651/error-the-details-of-the-application-error-from-being-viewed-remotely)** and also checked **[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18888528/how-to-remove-this-web-config-error-it-works-fine-on-local-host-but-if-i-upload)** but none of them were useful. My `web.config` file is as below:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=sometoken" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <!--<add key="MaintenanceMode" value="false" />-->
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="SessionTimeoutRedirect" value="true" />
    <add key="isAjaxHandled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <trust level="Full"/>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.0" defaultLanguage="c#"/>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="1048576" maxRequestLength="100000" />
    <globalization culture="en-IN" uiCulture="en-IN" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" defaultUrl="~/Admin/Index" timeout="2880" protection="Encryption" slidingExpiration="true" cookieless="AutoDetect" />
    </authentication>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MCBConnectionString" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.EntityDataModel.MCBEntityModel.csdl|res://*/Models.EntityDataModel.MCBEntityModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.EntityDataModel.MCBEntityModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=somesource;Network Library=;Packet Size=4096;Integrated Security=no;User ID=uid;Password=pwd;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=True; integrated security=no;connect timeout=120;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Below is the file structure in Plesk Admin panel

[image]

**One more thing to note:** If I remove `<trust level="Full"/>` tag from `web.config` I will not get any error but no display too. A blank page will be shown

Am really confused about this! I am left with no other alternatives except to approach this forum now! Any experts out there who faced this issue or anything I have to configure more on `web.config`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place The below code

`<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">`

instead of

```
<compilation targetFramework="4.0" defaultLanguage="c#"/>
```

hope it's works

**[This Link](https://help.1and1.com/hosting-c37630/scripts-and-programming-languages-c85099/aspnet-c39624/explanation-of-security-exception-error-a611691.html)** actually helps you to identify any sort of issues if it is not displayed in the server and thus I [OP] was able to fix my problem by identifying the issue.

Below is what the link contains:

> When using ASP.NET, you may encounter the following error: "Security
>   Exception" "Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException:
>   Security error."
>
> This means a class during runtime is linked against a restricted
>   class. By default ASP.NET error messages are optimized for
>   compile-time and run-time errors only. So the real error sources are
>   not displayed for linked errors. These errors arise for example, if
>   you try to access registry variables or system variables etc.
>   Sometimes you can get detailed error messages by placing the following
>   code in `global.asax` file.

```
<%@ Application %> 

<script runat="server" language="c#">
protected void Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e){
Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();
Server.ClearError();

Response.Write("<pre>");
Response.Write(Environment.NewLine);
Response.Write("Caught Exception: " + ex.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);

if (ex.InnerException != null){
Response.Write(Environment.NewLine);
Response.Write("Inner Exception: " + ex.InnerException.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
Response.Write(Environment.NewLine);
}

System.Security.SecurityException ex_security = ex as System.Security.SecurityException;

if (ex_security != null){
Response.Write(Environment.NewLine);
Response.Write("Security Exception Details:");
Response.Write(Environment.NewLine);
Response.Write("===========================");
Response.Write(Environment.NewLine);
Response.Write("PermissionState: " + ex_security.PermissionState + Environment.NewLine);
Response.Write("PermissionType: " + ex_security.PermissionType + Environment.NewLine);
Response.Write("RefusedSet: " + ex_security.RefusedSet + Environment.NewLine);
}

Response.Write("</pre>");
}
</script>
```

Comment: I've tried that possibility too buddy! :( I'll get the same error!!

Comment: <system.webServer>
      <defaultDocument enabled="true">    <!-- this line enables default documents for a directory -->
         <files>      
            <clear/>                 <add value="default.aspx"/>
         </files>
      </defaultDocument> before that you need to remove trust level=full

Comment: In my case its MVC and I will be having `.cshtml` files instead of `.aspx` which will be inside views! Any idea how to give default document for MVC?

Comment: routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "",        // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index"}  // Parameter defaults
        );

Comment: that is already there!! Everything is fine and works well in localhost!! Its some server configuration problem and I am not really getting what it is!!

Comment: I have also get this error in asp.net with three tier but after adding this the code shown in link i was enabled to perfect view on server following is the link  https://help.1and1.com/hosting-c37630/scripts-and-programming-languages-c85099/aspnet-c39624/explanation-of-security-exception-error-a611691.html

Comment: That was helpful to catch the proper error!! Let me try and let you know once I fix and publish it again.. +1 for efforts.. :)

Comment: ! Thank you sou much! I am accepting your because of the link you have given! I'll edit your answer and update the same with the link. Thanks once again!!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using asp.net mvc5, it needs full trust, which is not supported by plesk (host gator) at the moment I write this.

If that is the case you need to downgrade to mvc4 or find another hosting provider which supports full trust

Comment: _At the moment you write this_? What you write? I'll try your suggestion of downgrading to MVC4.

Comment: "At the moment I write this" is referring to asp.net mvc5 is not supported by plesk hostgator, but it may be or will be supported in future.